# How to automatically add letters to end of cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking for a solution to a problem I'm having trying to generate results quickly. I've searched a lot for answers but can't find specifically what I'm looking for

I have a serial number, where I want to copy down to multiple cells (like dragging a number to generate), but changing the letters at the end of it.

For example, taking the cell ZL24N65A and copying cells to get all the way to ZL24N65Z. Is that something that's even possible?

Comment: Easiest way to do this is to `concatenate`, and put the last letter in a 2nd column. ZL24N65 in column A all the way down, A-Z in column B, and then in column C concatenate A&B.

Comment: Spikey is correct, you can do this **fastest** using a helper column.   If you need to go "on beyond Z" then the answer becomes slightly more difficult, but you can write a quick formula in the helper column to handle whatever rules you want.

Comment: If you want to go past Z, just start your helper column at AA through to AZ, BA....and so on

Answer (score 8):

You can use this formula:

```
="ZL24N65"&CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,1,65))
```

`SEQUENCE` will create a list of integers 26 items long, starting at 65. Passing that list into `CHAR` will create a list that represents the capitalized alphabet. We are then prepending the leading characters to that list.

[image]

Comment: Just in case someone tries this and it doesnt work: `SEQUENCE` is an [Office 365 function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90).

Comment: Is `&` preferred over `CONCATENATE`?

Comment: It's functionally the same. I would only use the function if I wanted to string lots of columns and text together. For two items, the ampersand is simpler to type and read.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know your data in `A1`, you can use:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)&CHAR(CODE(RIGHT(A1))+1)
```

As I mentioned in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/krp4kd/creating_a_list_that_adds_sequence_of_letters_to/gib3msf?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) cross-post (though on a different website)

Answer (score -1):

TO add the specified text string or characters to the end of all selected cells in the excel you can use the concatenate operator or the concatenate function to create the excel formula.

Comment: This doesn't provided any information not yet available in existing answers