# Incremental text strings in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have part serial number like BALADWAT that I need to increment like BALADWAU, BALADWAV, BALADWAW and so on in column in excel. How do I go about this?

Comment: You can use the approach here: https://superuser.com/questions/1615511/how-to-automatically-add-letters-to-end-of-cell/1615529#1615529

Comment: You can use a helper column, and concatenate the first part of the string with the helper value.

Comment: What comes after `BALADWAZ`?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - it's `BALADWAZ` all the way down.

Comment: If you get the BALADWAZ what's the next text? BALADWBA?

Comment: BALADWBA is after BALADWAZ

Answer (score 0):

If
`A1: BALADWAT`

Then
`A2: =LEFT($A$1,LEN($A$1)-1) &CHAR(MIN(CODE(RIGHT($A$1))+ROWS($A$1:A1),90))`

and fill down.

[image]

**Algorithm**

- Convert the last character of the string to its ASCII code
- As you fill down the formula, the `ROWS` function will adjust and add `1` for each row that is filled down.
- Let that value increment to a maximum value of `90` (ascii code for `"Z"`
- Change it back to a letter with the `CHAR` function.
- Concatenate with the beginning of the string